# AltoRouter does not enter in map method

Tags: php, altorouter

Hello I download AltoRouter manuely and I try it the connection is good in the AltoRouter.php class but when I run the code in map fonction doesn't be executed. Here it's my code.

```
<?php  require('../foldername/foldername/AltoRouter.php');
 //require('header01.php');
 //require('header02.php');

 $router = new AltoRouter();
  $router->map('GET','/',function(){
   echo 'papa';// this code doesn't be executed when I run the app
 });
 //require('footer.php');
?>
```

If someone can help me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The code inside map it's not executed
Nothing appear only white page, if I uncomment header01.php and footer.php ligne I see the header and the footer code executed but echo 'papa'; it's not executed.